# P5.play.js keyDown instruction dosen't work

Tags: javascript, html

does anybody know why this piece of code doesn't work? I am using p5 libraries like p5.play,p5.js.p5.sound,p5dominm or smth like that. Heres the piece of code :

```
class Player{
constructor(){
    this.x,
    this.y,
    this.width,
    this.height
}



if(keyPressed(d)) {
    player.x=player.x+6;
    distance=distance+0.5
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a class you need to create an instance of the class. Try this way:

```
class Player{
constructor(){
    this.x,
    this.y,
    this.width,
    this.height
}

const player = new Player();

if(keyPressed(d)) {
    player.x=player.x+6;
    distance=distance+0.5
}
```